# Найти последние слова в тексте php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите - как найти в тексте с помощью PHP последние 4 слова?
Текст может быть случайным, по этому я не могу просто написать количество символов с конца строки.

*Например у меня есть текст, и я хочу сделать жирными последние 4 слова в этом тексте не зная содержания текста, как мне это сделать?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
$string = 'Например у меня есть текст, и я хочу сделать жирными последние 4 слова в этом тексте не зная содержания текста, как мне это сделать?';
$array = explode ( ' ', $string );
$last4word = implode ( ' ', array_slice($array, count($array)-4, 4));
echo $last4word; // 'как мне это сделать?'
```

разбиваем строку по пробелам и получаем строку из среза последних четырех элементов. Знаки препинания оставляем.